# Node.js will not Update to Latest Version

Tags: node.js, linux, command-line, npm, npm-install

I currently have node.js version v7.6.0

According to documentation, v8.5.0 is the latest version of node.

I have tried installing it using https://nodejs.org/en/

```
    node -v returns v7.6.0.
```

I have tried the following commands in Terminal:

```
    [sudo] npm install npm@latest -g
    npm install npm@latest -g
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo n 0.8.21
    sudo n latest
    lsb_release -a
```

Each command appears to recognize and install the latest version, but the final message reads:

Installed: v7.6.0

I've altered my BASH Profile to include:

```
    /usr/local/bin/node
    /usr/local/bin/npm
```

My version still shows v7.6.0 as the current version running.

Side Note:
My NPM is up-to-date at version 5.4.2

Is there any other way to update my Node to the current version?

Comment: You can manage your npm version with use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: Thank you!

        nvm use system
        nvm run system --version

These commands updated me to version v8.4.0

Now working on v8.5.0

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update to the latest version of node, use commands:

```
    nvm use system
    nvm run system --version
    nvm install node
```

These commands will bring you to the latest version of node.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### **Node** :

Don't worry about the current node version which is installed already.
Just download and install the latest version from https://nodejs.org/en
and run the installation wizard.
(Note: The installation takes care of removing the existing node version and updates to the latest! )

You can verify the updated version by running:

```
node -v
```

[image]

### **NPM** : (without NVM)

To upgrade npm to the latest version on Windows, you can use the following command in the Command Prompt or PowerShell:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

After running the command, npm will download and install the latest version. Once the installation is complete, you can verify the updated version by running:

```
npm --version
```

Hope this helps!
[image]